# Visualforce Email template - merge fields not working

Tags: visualforce, email-template, visualforce-template

I need to populate the merge field for the related accounts creator/owner.

I have these details:-

```
  <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Employers initiating Enrollment for Employees" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Contact">

       <p style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; color: #555555; ont-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0;">
              Questions? <br/>
              Contact: {!RelatedTo.Account.CreatedBy.Name} ;<br/>
              Email: {!RelatedTo.Account.CreatedBy.Email} &nbsp;<br/>
              <apex:outputLabel value="Phone: "  
                      rendered="{!RelatedTo.Account.CreatedBy.Phone != null}"/> 
              <apex:outputLabel value="{!RelatedTo.Account.CreatedBy.Phone}" rendered="{!RelatedTo.Account.CreatedBy.Phone != null}" />&nbsp;<br/>
              <apex:outputLabel value="Mobile: "  rendered="{!RelatedTo.Account.CreatedBy.MobilePhone != null}"/>

              {!RelatedTo.Account.CreatedBy.MobilePhone} &nbsp;<br/>

        </p>
```

Name is populating, Email, Phone and MobilePhone are not.
Send test and anonymous working fine.

Comment: when is being sent this email? Basic checks: visibility, permissions, ...

Comment: Contact/Lead/user can not be used for `relatedTo`; use `recipient.Account.CreatedBy.Name`

Comment: I solved by creating Visualforce component and adding without sharing controller to it.